# asp.Net how to set left side of a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web control button on a web form.

In my code behind c# want to move it 10 pixels to the left.

How to do it?

Comment: Help yourself by adding some code.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in the code behind?  Give more details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: A button doesn't have a let property- so how?

Comment: When I click button A and handle in on server, I want to move button B 10 pixels to the left.

Comment: You could assign a class to the button where the class(style) has a padding or left-margin of 10px.

Comment: Thus something like btnB.Left -= 10 would be nice, like in old VB and win forms

Comment: no properties for location?

Comment: @jkally, all WebControls have a Style property that can be used to set CSS attributes in C#. Could this really not be found before posting a question..?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.style%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I hope you're not going to post back to the server _just_ to do that? If so, do it client side.

Comment: @jkally web controls don't have position properties like windows controls do because that's not how HTML works.  You have to use CSS styles or other html containers (tables, etc.) to forces controls into specific positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Button buttonb = new Button();
buttonb.Attributes.Add("Style", "margin-left:10px");
```

Comment: Thanks. I Guess this is as close as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

I know you might not want this but using jQuery or javascript may be a good option for you.

```js
$('button').click(
    function(){
        $(this).css('margin-left', '-=10px');
    });
```

```css
button {
    margin: 0 0 0 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>I'm a button</button>
```